# Why Django show me the path to the template but do not load the template himselfe into the page?

Tags: python, django, templates

In the static folder of my DjangoServer is located a template of the default webpage. It's decorated with some template blocks.

If I load this template file, the path to the template is shown in the browser, it looks like, that the code is not loaded.

If I store the template in an app/template folder and I extend this file. It works very well. I use the tutorial of Django but it still not working.

**Settings.py**
django.contrib.staticfiles is added to INSTALLED_APPS

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

**projectRootFolder/static/html/basePage.html**

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% block head %}
    <title>{% block title %}My amazing site{% endblock %}</title>
      {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
    {% block body %}
    <header>
        {% block header %}
            <header> -- HEADER BANNER --</header>
            {% block menu %}<nav></nav>{% endblock %}
        {% endblock %}
    </header>

    <section>
        {% block section %} SECTION {% endblock %}
    </section>

        {% block footer %}
            <footer> -- FOOTER --</footer>
        {% endblock %}
 {%  endblock %}
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'angularjs/SOME_ANGULAR_FILES_LOADED.js' %}"></script>
</html>
```

**app/template/app/index.html from an app**

```
{% load  static from staticfiles %}
{% static "html/basePage.html" %}
{% block menu %}<nav><a href="/heatingControll">App A</a></nav>{% endblock %}
{% block section %} Lorem Ipsum{% endblock %}
```

**app/views.py**

```
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# PAGE CALLS
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('mainControll/index.html')
    context = {}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

**Output**

[image]

What is the mistake i've made? How can I load this template correctly?

Comment: Show your view. I suspect you are not actually rendering this template, but serving it statically; if you were rendering it, you would get an error because `extends` must be the first line in a template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanke you, I've updated this part of my question

Comment: You still didn't show your view. And from your comment on Lynoure's answer, why is the base template in your static directory? Templates are not static files.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Now the content of `app/views.py` is added to the question. I located the `basePage.html` template there, because in my oppinon it is defined one times an should not changed. What is your oppinion?

Comment: It's not a question of opinions. Templates *must* go in the template directory, otherwise they do not work. Put your template in the right place, then use `extend`, and things will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Warning***, this answer assumes your goal for asking the question is to get things to work, instead of helping you troubleshoot a probable permission problem just so that you can run into another problem. That is, I'm assuming your end goal is not a html document inside a non-html document.

### What can you do to get your output to work:

It looks like you want to include a template into another template, you can do that with {% extends "basePage.html" %}. Your template does then need to be at a location where templates are found, not where static pages are found.

E.g. If your app is called 'myapp' then under myapp/templates/ is a one possible place, assuming the TEMPLATES setting has APPDIRS = True

This would mean changing index.html to be

```
{% extends "basePage.html" %}
{% block menu %}<nav><a href="/heatingControll">App A</a></nav>{% endblock %}
{% block section %} Lorem Ipsum{% endblock %}
```

See https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/template_extending/ for example of this and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#configuration for configuring things to that your basePage.html can be found

Comment: While link only answers are okay, please explain the main parts here.

Comment: Thanks @Praveen 
I did my best to improve the answer accordingly, but I clearly don't type fast enough for this site, or I have no idea what 'useful' means :)

Comment: @Lynoure basePage.html is located in the static root folder of the project, with `{% extends "basePage.html" %}` I do not can load this file. If I use  `..\..\static\html\basePage.html` I get an error, becouse it's not allowed to traverse the direcotry.

Comment: @michael-mammut I would recommend putting templates into the template locations instead. e.g. into ~/myproject/myapp/templates/ assuming your TEMPLATES configuration has 'APP_DIRS': True,